# How can I use 'linear-gradient' for fixed background image with CSS

Tags: css, background-image, gradient, fixed, linear-gradients

I am using `linear-gradient` for my `background-image`. That was working well until I set `background-attachment` to `fixed`.

How can I do same effect with `background-attachment: fixed;`

```css
.photo {
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom, 
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%, 
      rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%
    ),
    url(https://s30.postimg.org/v67rh5bdd/image.jpg);
  background-attachment: unset; /* 'fixed' does not work */
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55vh;
  position: absolute;
}
.panel {
  margin-top:30vh;
}
.panel-body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div clasas="row">
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

or jsbin: http://jsbin.com/miqizetoqu/edit?css,output

Comment: is the intention to have the white gradient "move over to top" of the fixed picture, or to have both remain fixed to the top of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a pseudo element on the `.photo` div to hold the gradient. This can be positioned absolutely over the top of the image.

```
.photo {
  background-image: url(https://s30.postimg.org/v67rh5bdd/image.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.photo::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  background: 
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom, 
      rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%, 
      rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 82%, 
      rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 84%, 
      rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 86%,
      rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 88%, 
      rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 90%, 
      rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 92%,
      rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 94%, 
      rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 96%, 
      rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 98%,
      rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%
    );
}
```

See this bin:

http://jsbin.com/tepalahipe/edit?css,output